# how to point $HOME/.dmrc to new partition preserving 644

Tags: dual-boot

have mint and windows dual booted however when I attempt to point mint (or ubuntu 13.10 for that matter) to the ntfs common /home I get $HOME/.dmrc ignore error how to fix or is there another filesystem that both can read natively as I move files back and forth alot...

doesn't seem to affect anything else (that i can tell but popup at boot is becoming annoying as is my lack of knowledge to fix)

Comment: You can not use NTFS for a home partition (without problems). You will need to use a Linux native partition (ext4, etc).

Comment: not so worried about the perms elsewhere was just banking tired of the popup dialog ended up going fc20-design64 and win7ult64 but appreciate the confirmation